# How can i do viewpager with thumbnail image like flipkart app

Tags: android, android-viewpager, thumbnails

I would like to integrate viewpager like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flipkart.android this.

Here What i tried,

I found some useful samples from here https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView. But it should not able to click thumbnail image like flipkart.

What i need is,

I need viewpager swipe with thumbnail image like flipkart.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand about what thumbnail you said. Maybe you mean yellow page indicator?

Comment: hi Eldar, I need like this http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/